# Retrive Firestore object flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do i access the [address]--->[street] in flutter?

Below is what i currently have.

```
String addressStreet = snapshot.data.documents[index].data['address'].toString();
print(addressStreet);
```

[image]

Comment: snapshot.data.documents[index]['address']['street].toString();

Answer (score 2):

```
Firestore.instance.collection('registered_users').document(usersID).get().then((result){
    List<dynamic> address = result.data['address'];
});
```